# multer not uploading multiple images node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, file-upload, multer

I have a react application trying to upload multiple files using formdata. It seems to be able to do upload.single() but not upload.array() on the backend. And I cannot figure out why.

Function handling the upload when a button is clicked

```
  const handleUpload = async () => {
    let data = new FormData();
    data.append("files", imageList);
    data.append("title", title);
    data.append("short_text", shortText);
    data.append("news", news);
    const response = newsUpload(data);
    console.log(response);
  };
```

The api function on the front-end

```
export const newsUpload = async (data) => {
  return await api
    .post(`api/news/upload`, data)
    .then((data) => {
      return "DONE!";
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err.response.data);
    });
};
```

Back-end:
I instantiate the multer instance in the server.js file which is the run file.

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "uploads/");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, req.userId + Date.now() + ".jpeg");
  },
});
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });
```

and I then send the upload function into the router:

```
require("./app/routes/news.routes")(app, upload);
```

news.routes.js defines the route for api/news/upload with the upload.array() being sent through:

```
app.post(
    "/api/news/upload",
    [authJwt.verifyToken, authJwt.isAdmin],
    upload.array("files",5),
    controller.upload
  );
```

If I change the upload.array("files",5) to upload.single("file") and change the front-end accordingly, it works by uploading one file.

I have no idea why upload.array() doesnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that  `data.append("files", imageList);` was essentially appending an array to an array, so the file array sent to the api was [[Files]], instead of a required [Files].

Changing it to

```
for (let i = 0; i < imageList.length; i++) {
  data.append("files", imageList[i]);
}
```

Fixed the problem.